# Unable to install wubi on windows 7 home premium 64bit

Tags: wubi, proxy, authentication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wubi “could not retrieve the required disk image”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170105/wubi-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-image)

When I try to install wubi in a partition made on my hard disk I get a error message saying

```
"could not retrive the required disk image file for furthur details goto the
C:\Users\raghavadss\AppData\Local\Temp\wubi-12.04-rev269.log file"
```

which I have pasted in the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/1202911/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are behind a proxy web server that requires authentication. Wubi is trying to download the Ubuntu image file and failing.

See this old discussion on [HTTP Proxy for wubi](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=767914). Also see [Wubi "could not retrieve the required disk image"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170105/wubi-could-not-retrieve-the-required-disk-image).

**One solution is to download the image manually and then tell wubi where to look for it.**

Even though you plan to put Ubuntu in its own partition, Wubi will use a virtual partiton , a big file called root.disk to install the operating system and all the user data. Because of this, compared with a regular installation, a Wubi installation faces some limitations.

1. In the Wubi installation the filesystem is more vulnerable to hard
   reboots. Also, if the Windows drive is unmounted uncleanly (most
   commonly because of a Windows crash), Ubuntu will not be able to
   mount the Windows drive and boot until Windows has successfully
   booted and shut down. If the Windows system cannot be booted after
   the crash, the user also cannot boot Ubuntu.
2. Performance related to hard-disk access is also slightly slower,
   more so if the disk image file is fragmented, on a Wubi install
   compared to a normal one.

See more at: [What's the difference between Wubi and a regular "alongside Windows" installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615/whats-the-difference-between-wubi-and-a-regular-installation)

**Alternate Suggestion:**

Since you have already created a partition for Ubuntu, it will be ideal to do a proper (not wubi) installation of Ubuntu in its own partition. This will allow you to format the Ubuntu partition ext4 and use it more effectively.